# How to make substitute() use another magic mode?

Tags: substitute

The doc about the substitute function [`:h substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) tells us:

> [...] the matching with {pat} is **always done like the 'magic' option is set** [...]

That's cool but what if I need to use `substitute()` with another mode like say, verymagic or verynomagic? Is there a way to modify this behavior?

I guess a flag won't help me since the same doc topic says:

> [...] When {flags} is "g", all matches of {pat} in {expr} are replaced.  Otherwise {flags} should be "".

---

So here are my two questions:

- Is it possible to modify the magic mode used by `substitute()`?
- If it is not possible, what is the most elegant/efficient way to perform a substitution on a string contained in a variable with another magic mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by including escapes in the pattern that change the magic mode.

From `:help pattern`

> Use of "\m" makes the pattern after it be interpreted as if 'magic' is set,
>   ignoring the actual value of the 'magic' option.
>   Use of "\M" makes the pattern after it be interpreted as if 'nomagic' is used.
>
> Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except
>   '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.  "very magic"
>
> Use of "\V" means that in the pattern after it only the backslash and the
>   terminating character (/ or ?) has a special meaning.  "very nomagic"

Comment: Damn I probably don't have all of my head today, I was trying to add the mode in the `{expr}` part instead of the `{pat}` part...

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? For me `:echo substitute("foo123", "\v.", "x", "g")` returns `foo123`

Comment: @Wolfie, it should either be `"\\v."` (double quotes) or `'\v'` (single quotes).

Comment: Which is why just about any regexp in Vim that is supposed to be used on more than one computer has to start with either `\m`, `\v`, or `\V`. There's a similar problem with case sensitivity, where `ignorecase` and `smartcase` boobytrap most command / functions / whatever that use regexps, to the effect that you also need to specify either `\C` or `\c` everywhere where you care about case. This also makes things _interesting_ for multibyte encodings, but that's from another story. Ah, the fractal beauty of design mistakes in Vim. :)